What does mean Sync/Async in event table
I came across an interesting table of events at https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents. However, I am not familiar with the category Sync / Async.



Event Type
Sync / Async
Bubbling Phase
Trusted event
target types DOM Interface
Cancelable
Default Action




click
Sync
Yes
Element
PointerEvent
Yes
Varies: for targets with an associated activation behavior, executes the activation behavior; for focusable targets, gives the element focus.


error
Async
No
Window, Element
Event
No
None


input
Sync
Yes
Element
InputEvent
No
None


load
Async
No
Window, Document, Element
Event
No
None


mouseover
Sync
Yes
Element
MouseEvent
Yes
None


mouseup
Sync
Yes
Element
MouseEvent
Yes
None


select
Sync
Yes
Element
Event
No
None


unload
Sync
No
Window, Document, Element
Event
No
None


wheel
Async
Yes
Element
WheelEvent
Yes
Scroll (or zoom) the document



Could someone please explain what this category means?
For example: what is the difference between the Sync click event and the Async wheel event?

I can't access the site so I'm not entirely sure but usually Sync/Async is about blocking. I guess Sync clicks will block each other while Async wheels will not.

@LãNgọcHải try using a proxy or the site web.archive.org to open my link. Would be nice if can give an answer.

There used to be a section explaining this, you can still see it in the previous edition of the same document.
It reads

Events may be dispatched either synchronously or asynchronously.
Events which are synchronous ("sync events") are treated as if they
are in a virtual queue in a first-in-first-out model, ordered by
sequence of temporal occurrence with respect to other events, to
changes in the DOM, and to user interaction. Each event in this
virtual queue is delayed until the previous event has completed its
propagation behavior, or been canceled. Some sync events are driven by
a specific device or process, such as mouse button events. These
events are governed by the event
order
algorithms defined for that set of events, and user agents will
dispatch these events in the defined order.
Events which are asynchronous ("async events") may be dispatched as
the results of the action are completed, with no relation to other
events, to other changes in the DOM, nor to user interaction.

[EXAMPLE 3]
During loading of a document, an inline script element is parsed and executed. The
load event is
queued to be fired asynchronously at the script element. However,
because it is an async event, its order with relation to other
synchronous events fired during document load (such as the
DOMContentLoaded event from
[HTML5])
is not guaranteed.


It has been removed along with its parent section as part of https://github.com/w3c/uievents/issues/372, which makes the point that the parent section is already mainly covered by the DOM specs. However it's true that the specific bit about sync/async isn't there either and thus this concept isn't backed by anything anymore.
I added a comment on the issue to let them know about it.

Ps: hopefully one day all the UI Events specs will be owned by WHATWG and made less "magical".

Mmm interesting. But what interests me most is the order in which synchronous events are executed with asynchronous ones. Let's say we have accumulated a queue of 100 click events, when clicks on the 60th element (at the time of addition) were added to this queue, the load event occurred. What is the order of execution then? Let's assume that the computer is just thinking for a long time and this is why such a queue occurred :)

Since they won't use the same task-source, and one is sync and the other async, that's implementation defined and browsers have various heuristics to decide which task they'll favor over another, e.g. they have some starvation system to avoid running the same task-source too long even though it would usually have higher priority (IIRC click would have higher priority in at least  Chrome and FF).

Excuse me, but what are you referring to when you say that they use not the same task sources? Is this written anywhere in the specification?

Also there is a note: There can be interactions between different event orders. For example, a click event might be modified by a concurrent keydown event (e.g., via Shift+click). However, the event orders of these different event sources would be distinct. What does mean click might be modified?

1/2 You didn't say which load event is fired, so it's hard to pinpoint a particular place in the specs, but you can start from https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#event-load, click on the "load" hyperlink to see the cross-links. In there if we take e.g. the 
2/2 but it's commonly agreed that the UI task source is meant for these. As for the modified event what they mean is the properties like ctrlKey, altKey, or here specifically shiftKey, and others that do depend on other events from other devices (here keyboard ones).

To summarize my understanding: synchronous events are those events that are dependent on other events, for example, pressing the left mouse button triggers a group of events mousedown -> mouseup -> click as a task; On the contrary, asynchronous events are those that do not have a dependency on other events, so loading a picture or script that will set the task of "completing the loading" and event load will be independent of other events. But there is a nuance: the abort event is specified to be asynchronous, how do we understand this? How do you understand this Kaiido?

And yet, the wheel event is indicated as asynchronous, but why? It is completely synchronous, if I got the all theory of this correctly, ctrl+wheel up changes the behavior in the document, it switchs from the scrolling to sizing. Something is wrong here.

Honestly I don't know how they picked which one should be sync which one should be async. It's indeed very surprising that wheel is async and abort is sync, but your understanding seems off anyway: between a mousedown and a mouseup there might be many tasks and many events from the same device (e.g. mousemove when dragging). But since they come from the same device, it's not the ones that need to be synchronized. Instead it's more between a keyboard and a mouse send their events at the same time.

Take this fiddle as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/yh98tfs1/ When pressing the Shift key it will lock the event loop for 3s. If you do click during these 3 seconds, you could have either already released the Shift key, in case the mouse event's shiftKey should be false, or you could have it still pressed. Since the Event object will be built only after the event-loop has been freed again, the potential keyup event must be fired in the same order it was fired relatively to the mousedown one, so that when the mouse event is built it has the correct state. These need to be synchronized.

Also, please note that they are working toward getting rid entirely of this notion and instead develop a more algorithmic spec: https://w3c.github.io/uievents/event-algo.html I don't think you should spend too much time on that notion, it's known it's bad.

Well, I seem to have understood everything correctly, following the order of events, when I described the order of three mouse events this refers to the order of the process (yes, what you expanded with other events is optional, I saw it in the specification here), and your example with fiddle refers to the order of the device. Or I'm wrong?

Could you give me examples for this sentence: Some sync events are driven by a specific device or process? What is driven by device and what is driven by
process? If you explain this point, I will definitely understand the concept, it is last what I wanted to know. P.S Sorry, for a lot of questions.
